# Restoring an AWS RDS DB but in a different security group other than "default"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am working on a process to accomplish the following goal:

1. Copy a DB snapshot from one region to the next.
2. After copying the DB to the next region, I want to restore it.
3. I want to also put the newly restored DB instance into a separate VPC other than "default", so that I can have my AWS Workspaces clients get to it.

I've got steps 1 and 2 working perfectly; however, it doesn't seem like the process to restore a DB instance from a snapshot gives you a lot of options from the API. Here's the API process according to AWS's documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/RDS/Client.html#restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot-instance_method

According to those options, the only option I see available anywhere remotely related to the VPC is the `vpc_security_ids`; however, I tried specifying a `vpc_security_id` that belongs into the VPC that I want the RDS instance to be restored to, btu I got the following error in the console:

```
Aws::RDS::Errors::InvalidParameterCombination: The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs. The DB instance is in vpc-76cf380e and the EC2 security group is in vpc-012999f6551c713c6
from /Users/nutella/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.113.1/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:17:in `call'
```

It's clearly possible to do this from the RDS console when restoring a snapshot, as you can just simply select the VPC that you want to restore the db instance into, but it's not clear on how to do this with the SDK.

Comment: Does the `restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot` call specify a DBSubnetGroupName in the target vpc?

Comment: Just as you typed that, I literally just realized that's what I was missing. After implementing it and testing it, that worked. Thanks so much as well!